# SQL 2014 Express Failing to Update

Tags: sql-server, sql, windows-server-2016, solidworks

Our server has been restarting periodically and I think I've tracked it down to a memory leak in our Solidworks PDM SQL server, after contacting our VAR they said they've encountered this issue and it was resolved by updating SQL Express 2014 SP3 and installing the cumulative update.

I followed their instructions (which matched microsofts instructions) and it looked like everything worked fine but in the multiple locations you can check the version they all still say it's running SP1.

I can't seem to find any other cases of this online, anyone have any insight or ideas to try?

System specs:
Intel Xeon 1230 V5
Windows server essentials 2016
16 gigs KVR24E17D8/16 kingston RAM
250W single power supply

Thanks!

Comment: What locations are telling you you're still using SP1?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I've never set anything up to tell anything what version of SQL is in use.

Comment: You say "multiple lications you can check the version they all still say it's running SP1". What locations?

Comment: Oh, if I use "select @@version" in a query and in properties of the server the version number corresponds to sp1

Comment: Is that the effective SQL version of the database, or of the engine? Running `select` may just be querying the database, not the engine it's running in. I may be incorrect, but that's my first guess sans much research. I would also suggest reading this MS document on getting SQL Server Express versions: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321185/how-to-determine-the-version-edition-and-update-level-of-sql-server-an

Comment: Every option on that list returns 2014 SP1 "Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1-GDR) (KB4019091) - 12.0.4237.0 (X64)   Jul  5 2017 22:03:42   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: )" to be exact.